# jQuery validate is not working when the button is outside the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, validation

I have a problem where jQuery validate is not working when the submit button is placed outside the form tags (which is required form my Cordova mobile app). As soon as `.validate` is called, the execution stops.

My HTML is set-up this way:

```
<form id="form-cart" >
  // All form fields here
</form>

<ons-bottom-toolbar>
  <button class="button" onclick="addToBasket();" data-trn-key="add_to_basket">
  Add to Basket
  </button>
</ons-bottom-toolbar>
```

And the function is then called as:

```
function addToBasket()
{   
    $.validate({    
        form : '#form-cart',    
        borderColorOnError:"#FF0000",
        onError : function() {    
        },      
        onSuccess : function() {  
        // Run ajax on success
              } 
            };   
            sNavigator.pushPage("confirmation.html", options);             
           return false;
        }  
    });
}
```

How can I get this working so that it validates and calls ajax even if the button is outside of the form tags?

Comment: Wait a second... are you sure you're using [the jQuery Validate plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org)?  `form`, `borderColorOnError`, `onError`, and `onSuccess` are not valid options for this plugin.

Comment: Based on your code, you are not using what is most commonly referred to as the jQuery Validate plugin.  Edited tags.

Answer (score 2):

According to jQuery validation plugin [documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) there are two different methods:

`validate()` – Validates the selected form.

`valid()` – Checks whether the selected form or selected elements are valid.

So you should set up the form validation with `.validate` method outside your function and check if form is valid inside your function (see code example below):

```
$('#form-cart').validate({    

});

function addToBasket() {   
    if ($('#form-cart).valid()) 
        //do you onSuccess stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, and also according to this documentation, the `.validate()` method must be attached to a selector representing the form, and the OP's parameters, `form`, `borderColorOnError`, `onError`, and `onSuccess`, are totally meaningless.

Comment: Thank you, I've fixed the validate part

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<form id="form-cart" >
    // All form fields here
    // Don't give <input type="submit"> here
</form>

<ons-bottom-toolbar>
    <button type="submit" id="submitBtn" class="button" onclick="addToBasket();" data-trn-key="add_to_basket">
    Add to Basket
    </button>
</ons-bottom-toolbar>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submitBtn").click(function () {
        $("#form-cart").submit();
    });
});
```